# Elasticsearch Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have set up a Hadoop cluster with 3 DataNodes and 1 NameNode. I have also installed elasticsearch on one of the DataNodes. But I'm not able to access the HDFS using elasticsearch.(Hadoop cluster and Elasticsearch are working fine independently) Now, I want to integrate my Hadoop cluster with elasticsearch. I found there is a seperate plugin for that. But I'm not able to download it.(bin/plugin -i elasticsearch/elasticsearch-repository-hdfs/1.3.0.M3 command is not working. It is failing everytime I executed it). Can anyone suggest me which plugin I should download. Also the path to place that plugin and how to aceess it using the url.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there an error for the failed download you can share?

Comment: You can integrate the hadoop & Elasticsearch via Hive. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/hive.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**1)** Download jars from this [link](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/elasticsearch-hadoop-1.3.0.BUILD-20140501.012020-413.zip)

**2)** Unzip it and place the jars in plugin folder of Elasticsearch

**3)** restart the server and start using it..!

Comment: How will I use it? Through url??

Comment: after plugin available... follow this link to configure...  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html

Comment: the link you have given to download the jars is showing 404 error.

Comment: pls try this  https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/elasticsearch-hadoop-1.3.0.BUILD-20140501.012020-413.zip

Comment: I have done the configurations. Now how will I be able to use it? Can I access it through url like we access normal elasticsearch with port 9200?

Comment: HADOOP_CLASSPATH: HADOOP_CLASSPATH="<colon-separated-paths-to-your-jars-including-elasticsearch-hadoop>
Now I have jars in elasticsearch/plugins. So writing  HADOOP_CLASSPATH="/elasticsearch/plugins/" will be fine?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to use [this repo](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop).

It's an Elasticsearch real-time search and analytics natively integrated with Hadoop and you can follow the documentation provided [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/index.html) to use it.

The repo is provided by [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/hadoop/).

Comment: Thanks a ton for your reply.
I have already placed that repo in plugin folder of elasticsearch. Is that correct? Should I do any configuration settings in that? And please tell me how to use it, I mean how to access it using url after evrything is done.

Comment: I haven't worked with that repo quite much yet, but you can find the configurations [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop#usage) and [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html) on the official page. They explain it better than will I think ;)

Answer (score 0):

The elasticsearch hadoop library is not a plugin. You need to download or build it and put it into the classpath of the hadoop/spark application you will use.